# Does Italy require a COVID-19 vaccination less than 9 months ago?

Tags: europe, covid-19, italy

A friend of mine sent me this [link](https://www.dgc.gov.it/web/faq.html#pvaccinate) to an official Italian government website which mentions (Google Translate translation):

> From December 15, 2021, the validity of the COVID-19 green
> certification for vaccination, for doses following the first or dose
> after recovery, passes from 12 to 9 months from the date of
> administration. Check when you have taken the last dose, if more than
> 9 months have passed, you are among those who would find themselves
> without COVID-19 Green Certification as a result of this variation.
> Book your booster dose by December 14, 2021, and you will receive the
> new Certification within 48 hours of administering the vaccine, which
> will be valid for 9 months.

Does it mean that access to Italy will be limited to those with <9 months of vaccine validity?

Comment: Where are you travelling from/what are the countries you will have visited in the 14 days before reaching Italy? Rules vary a lot depending on the countries involved, but in many cases, even without vaccination you can enter, you just have more requirements/restrictions. Entering with vaccination over 9 months ago would be equivalent to entering without vaccination.

Comment: op has not returned to clarify. vote to put on hold.

Comment: @MarkMayo What sort of clarification are you looking for? OPs original question is fairly detailed and while jcaron's questions, if answered, can provide more detail, they do not look like a blocker for the question can be put on hold. To me the OP is asking a fairly straightforward question - Does Green certificate cease to be valid if >9 months have passed from vaccination.

Comment: @RedBaron fair, I was just noting jcaron's qs not answered, but it's not an area of expertise of mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: That <9 months requirements is only relevant to accessing certain activities, such as restaurants / entertainment venues / ..

But access to Italy and trains does NOT require <9 months validity.